# Displaying images based on column colors

Tags: php, css

This code displays a lot of images based on color in columns. I'm thinking it can probably be optimized a lot better. But I'm wondering if anyone has a more fundamental solution on how this could be improved in regards to speed and legibility.

The database has the equivalent of [this XML file](http://ark42.com/mtg/gathererdownloader/MTGCardInfo/).

Any suggestions?

**CSS**

```
#row  {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-row;
}
#col0, #col1, #col2, #col3, #col4, #col5 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    $url_core_sets = "cards/HQ/Core Sets/";
    $url_expansion = "cards/HQ/Expansions/";
    $url_promoCards = "cards/HQ/Promo Cards/";
    $url_special_sets = "cards/HQ/Special Sets/";
    $url_low_rez = "cards/HQ/Low Rez/"; // low resolution cards (cards that are used when no alternative is available)
    $filetype = ".jpg";
    $width = 240;
    $height = 340;

    // figure out which folder the cards are in...
    if (file_exists($url_core_sets.$cards[0]['set'])) {
        $url = $url_core_sets;
    } else if (file_exists($url_expansion.$cards[0]['set'])) {
        $url = $url_expansion;
    } else if (file_exists($url_promoCards.$cards[0]['set'])) {
        $url = $url_promoCards;
    } else if (file_exists($url_special_sets.$cards[0]['set'])) {
        $url = $url_special_sets;
    } else if (file_exists($url_low_rez.$cards[0]['set'])) {
        $url = $url_low_rez;
    }

    // figure out file type...
    if(file_exists($url."/".$cards[0]['name'].".full.jpg")) {
        $filetype = ".full.jpg";
    }
    else {
        $filetype = ".jpg";
    }

    class CardData {
        public $name;
        public $full_path;
        public $cost;
    }

    $colors = array("B", "R", "G", "W", "U");
    $color_index = 0;
    $current_color = $colors[$color_index];
    $columns = array(array(), array(), array(), array(), array(), array());
    for($i=0; $i<count($cards); $i+=1) {
        $card_data = new CardData();
        $card_data->name = htmlentities($cards[$i]['name']);
        $card_data->full_path = htmlentities($url.$cards[$i]['set']."/".$cards[$i]['name'].$filetype);
        $card_data->cost = $cards[$i]['cost'];

        $pos = strpos($card_data->cost, $current_color);
        for($j=0; $j<count($colors); $j+=1) { // check if other colors are being used in the current card
            if(strcmp($colors[$j], $current_color) != 0) { // if it's not the current color
                $other_colors = strpos($card_data->cost, $colors[$j]);
                if($other_colors !== false) { // different color is being used
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($pos === false || $other_colors !== false) { // color doesn't exists in current card OR different color is being used
            if($color_index < 5) {
                $color_index += 1; // next column
                $current_color = $colors[$color_index]; // keep track of current color
            }
        }

        array_push($columns[$color_index], $card_data);
    }

    $col0Index = 0;
    $col1Index = 0;
    $col2Index = 0;
    $col3Index = 0;
    $col4Index = 0;
    $col5Index = 0;
    while($col0Index != -1 || $col1Index != -1 || $col2Index != -1 || $col3Index != -1 || $col4Index != -1 || $col5Index != -1) {
?> 
    <div id="row">
        <div id="col0">
            <?php
                if($col0Index != -1) {
                    $name = $columns[0][$col0Index]->name;
                    if($name != "") {
                        $full_path = $columns[0][$col0Index]->full_path;
                        echo '<img src="'.$full_path.'" alt="'.$name.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'">';
                        $col0Index+=1;
                    }
                    else {
                        $col0Index = -1;
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="col1">
            <?php
                if($col1Index != -1) {
                    $name = $columns[1][$col1Index]->name;
                    if($name != "") {
                        $full_path = $columns[1][$col1Index]->full_path;
                        echo '<img src="'.$full_path.'" alt="'.$name.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'">';
                        $col1Index+=1;
                    }
                    else {
                        $col1Index = -1;
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="col2">
            <?php
                if($col2Index != -1) {
                    $name = $columns[2][$col2Index]->name;
                    if($name != "") {
                        $full_path = $columns[2][$col2Index]->full_path;
                        echo '<img src="'.$full_path.'" alt="'.$name.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'">';
                        $col2Index+=1;
                    }
                    else {
                        $col2Index = -1;
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="col3">
            <?php
                if($col3Index != -1) {
                    $name = $columns[3][$col3Index]->name;
                    if($name != "") {
                        $full_path = $columns[3][$col3Index]->full_path;
                        echo '<img src="'.$full_path.'" alt="'.$name.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'">';
                        $col3Index+=1;
                    }
                    else {
                        $col3Index = -1;
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="col4">
            <?php
                if($col4Index != -1) {
                    $name = $columns[4][$col4Index]->name;
                    if($name != "") {
                        $full_path = $columns[4][$col4Index]->full_path;
                        echo '<img src="'.$full_path.'" alt="'.$name.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'">';
                        $col4Index+=1;
                    }
                    else {
                        $col4Index = -1;
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="col5">
            <?php
                if($col5Index != -1) {
                    $name = $columns[5][$col5Index]->name;
                    if($name != "") {
                        $full_path = $columns[5][$col5Index]->full_path;
                        echo '<img src="'.$full_path.'" alt="'.$name.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'">';
                        $col5Index++;
                    }
                    else {
                        $col5Index = -1;
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

`$cards` has the following info in it:

```
$cards[$i]['id']
$cards[$i]['lang']
$cards[$i]['name']
$cards[$i]['cost']
$cards[$i]['type']
$cards[$i]['set']
$cards[$i]['rarity']
$cards[$i]['power']
$cards[$i]['toughness']
$cards[$i]['rules']
$cards[$i]['printedname']
$cards[$i]['printedtype']
$cards[$i]['printedrules']
$cards[$i]['flavor']
$cards[$i]['cardnum']
$cards[$i]['artist']
$cards[$i]['sets']
$cards[$i]['rulings']
```

Comment: I think you need to stop for a moment and collect your thoughts. What *exactly* is it you want to optimize/improve? Is it slow? Is the code getting unwieldy?

Comment: Starting from $colors = array("B", "R", "G", "W", "U"); where the heart of the code is, I'm trying to figure out if it could be fundamentally better, as in improvement in speed and legibility.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: Would be nice if there was a button that would move it to there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Unnecessary `strcmp`

Part of your code looks like this:

```
if(strcmp($colors[$j], $current_color) != 0) {
```

`strcmp` is not necessary here; plain equality would work fine and be clearer:

```
if($current_color !== $colors[$j]) {
```

## Repetition in Output

I notice you're repeating a lot of code when it comes to output. That should be a clear sign that a loop might be more appropriate. As is, if we were to interpret your `$columns` array as rows and output something like so:

```
foreach($columns as $column) {
    foreach($column as $cell) {
        echo "[]";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

it might look like this:

```
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
```

It would be much easier for us to output it if we could iterate over it the other way, if it were transposed:

```
[] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] []    [] []
[] [] []    [] []
[] [] []    [] []
[]    []       []
[]
[]
```

Fortunately, that's rather easy with [any of the transpose functions here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/797251). Once you do that, your repeated code can suddenly be condensed into this much clearer code:

```
$rows = transpose($columns);
foreach($rows as $row):
?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php for($columnIndex = 0; $columnIndex < 6; $columnIndex++): ?>
        <div class="col<?php echo $columnIndex; ?>">
        <?php
            $card = $row[$columnIndex];
            if(isset($card)):
        ?>
            <!-- snip -->
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php
endforeach;
```

Note also that I've changed your `id`s to `class`es. `id`s must be unique, but you're using many `id="row"` and `id="colN"` in a loop, rendering your document invalid. This is the perfect use case for `class`.

Taking this further, your CSS rules for each column are the same. Rather than having separate `col0`, `col1`, … classes, you could instead just have a `column` class and apply it to all of them.

Comment: I didn't really use this but I thought the transpose function was quite clever. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Good answer. But, there is so much more wrong with his code. For instance the 'CardData' class. Why use a class here with all the overhead when it's just a glorified array / stdClass instance? Not to speak about all those DRY-violations. So +1 for good answer, but -1 for incomplete answer

Comment: @Pinoniq: You're right that it's incomplete. I wasn't aiming to make it complete; I just listed one main concern (the code duplication) and a few other concerns. I really wasn't expecting this to be the only answer; I was really hoping that there would be another answer to pick up where I left off.